# Closure Compiler Multiple Output files with the same name

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Is there a way to minify all JS from a folder and output them to a different folder with the same name but with the the addition of .min on the filename?

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js js/*.js --js_output_file js_min/app.min.js
```

From this:

```
JS
-- hello.js
-- hello2.js
-- hello3.js
```

To this:

```
JS_MIN
-- hello.min.js
-- hello2.min.js
-- hello3.min.js
```

Comment: You would need to invoke the compiler for each file.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do as Chad suggests?  If you are running linux or MacOs you should be able to leverage the "native image" which do particularly well for this kind of thing.

Comment: Or use nailgun to avoid JVM startup time.

Comment: I ended up writing a couple of bash scripts, but you could use "make" or any tool that would manage dependencies, add common extern files, deal with error files, not recompile when already done, etc.